# Give an informal reason why this cannot be the gradient of a functoin

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, vector-analysis

Explain why $F(x,y) = \Big(\frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\Big)$ cannot be the gradient of a function (defined away from the origin). Can it be the gradient if we only require F and $f$ to be defined away from the y-axis?

My thoughts: So my initial thought is that we can back out $f$ to find $f(x,y) = -arctan(\frac{x}{y})$ and that is undefined at $y=0$.. but I don't think that in itself disqualifies it as a gradient.

Function looks like this, in case you're curious: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%28-y/%28x%5E2%2by%5E2%29%29)

Comment: What happens if you integrate a gradient around a closed loop?  What happens if you integrate this function around the unit circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain of the field $F$ is the plane with the origin removed, note this is not simply connected. Since the domain of $F$ is not simply connected you cannot conclude that $F$ must be conservative solely on the basis of the cross-partial criterion (i.e. curl$(F) = 0$).

To see why $F$ is not conservative consider the line integral of $F$ across the unit circle parameterized by $r(t) = < \cos(t), \sin(t) >$. Then $F(c(t)) \cdot c'(t) = 1 $, thus the line integral evaluates to $2\pi$. If $F$ were conservative then the line integral (or circulation) across any closed curve would be $0$.

However, even though the field isn't conservative on its domain, it is conservative in any smaller, simply connected domain like the upper half-plane, $y > 0$. For instance, in this upper half plane you can take $f(x,y) = \arctan(y/x)$ as a potential function for $F$.

Comment: Note you also could have taken the upper half-plane $x>0$, which is what the question alluded to when it said "away from y-axis".

Comment: "Since the domain isn't simply connected then $F$ defined on its domain is not a conservative field." Could you expand on this? The fact of being conservative does not depend on the domain, no? Only the theorem stating that "$F=<P,Q>$ is conservative if and only if $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$" needs in an essential way that the domain is simply connected (together with the continuity of $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$).

Comment: The theorem you cited has a hypothesis which requires that $F$ be on a simply connected domain. Thus the "cross-partial" condition or the $curl(F) = 0$ is not sufficient to conclude that $F$ is conservative, you also need a simply connected domain on top of that.

Comment: As an illustration of this fact. Even though $F$ satisfies the cross-partial condition you cited, if you take the closed line integral of $F$ across the unit circle you'll get an answer of $2\pi$; however, if $F$ were indeed conservative then the circulation across any closed loop is $0$.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote, no?

But you wrote something like "The domain is not simply connected so $F$ is not conservative" (exact quote in my previous comment).

Please tell me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Right, your understanding is correct. I just repeated the same thing over again for emphasis. Though it should actually be that $F$ is not necessarily conservative what actually tells you that $F$ is not conservative is that the closed line integral is not $0$. I'll edit the response to reflect that.

Comment: @Taladris Yep thanks for the comment, my previous conclusion was not necessarily true. I hope the amendment fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The function you gave is undefined in a lot more places other than the origin.

This example is discussed explicitly [in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields).

Comment: The wiki answer is a bit beyond what I'm looking for -- I can follow it, but I don't understand what disqualifies this as a gradient at a more basic, intuitive level